# reactjs routes get string on parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react router set up like:

```
const routes =  (
  <Router>

    <Route path={"audio" + "/:audio_url"} component={AudioView} />
    <Route path="*" component={ErrorView} />
  </Router>
)
```

Here I am passing my audio url like:

```
'play/3456'
```

when I pass access url like `'audio/play/3456'` it is redirecting me to `ErrorView`.
It should redirect me to `AudioView` right ?

What might be the issue here ??

Comment: I think audio/play/3456 does not match the audio/{url} pattern. Just put path='/audio' for your AudioView component (and likely use subroutes for inner routes)

Answer (score 2):

The route

```
<Route path={"audio" + "/:audio_url"} component={AudioView} />
```

matches only `audio/123`

You should include `play` in the route

```
<Route path="/audio/play/:id" component={AudioView}>
```

Or if you are not sure of the route pattern add *

```
<Route path="/audio/*" component={AudioView}>
```

remember this matches anything after `audio/`

If possible prefer the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Params don't span across URL fragments. If both `play` and `3456` should be params, you should define them separately.

```
<Route path='audio/:command/:audio_url' component={AudioView} />
```